# Android How to get Last Focused Activity after "Force Stop" the Application

Tags: java, android

I am developing android Application having number of activities. The requirement of the application is **When i "FORCESTOP" the application manually(Settings->Applications->ManageApplication->APP_NAME->FORCESTOP), the last focused activity(UI Page) to be displayed.** Can i get the Last focused Activity after ***FORCESTOP***ing the Application? Please help me with the sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep track of each activity change and save it to file (e.g. in your sharedpreferences) immediately when the change happens. Something like this

```
protected void onResume() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext()).edit();
    edit.putString("LastActiveActivity", this.getClass().getName());
    edit.commit();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Make sure you save the current activity in the `onResume()` method of **all** your activities.

When you restart you can read the last activity back from your preferences. This should be done in the `onCreate()` method of your main activity (the one that is specified as "LAUNCHER" in your manifest). Then start the activity with the name you've read back.